# The supremum norm is submultiplicative

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Is the following proof correct:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the space of continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$. We can equip $C(X)$ with the (edit: sorry, semi-)norm $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x\in X} |f(x)|.$ I want to prove that for $f,g \in C(X)$, $\lVert fg \rVert_\infty \leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty \lVert g \rVert_\infty $. Let $z \in X$ be arbitrary then
$$
\lvert f(z)g(z) \rvert \leq \lvert   \; \sup_{x} \lvert f(x) \rvert  g(z)  \;\rvert=\sup_{x} \lvert f(x) \rvert  \lvert    g(z)\rvert \leq \sup_{x} \lvert f(x) \rvert  \sup_{y} \lvert g(y) \rvert. 
$$

Since $z$ was arbitrary
$$
\sup_{z} f(z)g(z)\leq \sup_{x} f(x) \sup_{y} g(y)
$$

that is the sought.

Comment: $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x\in X} f(x)$ is not a norm!

Comment: Hamou? Is not a norm?

Comment: @IgorCaetanoDiniz As written, it's not nonnegative, and will also give $0$ on functions which are nonzero (e.g. consider $f(x) = - x^2$ on some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$). What you're looking for is $\sup_x |f(x)|$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:$|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|\,|g(x)|\leq\|f\|_{\infty} |g(x)|,\forall x\in X\,\,\,$

Comment: That shortens it :) thanks.

Comment: please could you elaborate to show, $||fg||$ $\le ||f|| \times ||g||$.